# Have Google deprecated regionCodes?

Tags: youtube-api

This question is in reference to the Youtube Data API.

The standard region feeds have not changed since the 2nd/3rd of February(depending on your time zone) for all countries and when using the new V3 API's ability to specify a regionCode to filter search results by the search results returned are not filtered by this parameter at all (but an error is not returned, so it is accepting it).

Here are the urls for some standard region feeds (for the latest uploaded videos, which is the easiest to show this issue with) so you can check for yourself:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/US/most_recent

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/UK/most_recent

I've checked the Youtube bug log, release log, updates, blog, RSS feed and everywhere else I could find and have not seen any mention of this issue.

In short I'm asking if Google have deprecated region support from Youtube?

Comment: You may be confusing standardfeeds and search. In search the regionCode parameter only filter out results that are not available in the country (like music videos in germany). I am not sure what means most_recent for a particular region code in the standardfeeds.

Comment: Thank you very much, that explains the behaviour I was experiencing perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube still has region support. You can try it via explorer in [videoCategories](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list).
On the other hand there is no standardfeeds in v3, at some poing there will be.

Your examples were for v2, even though suport continues there could be some ambiguity, I'll follow up.