# YouTube API v3: language filter

Tags: youtube-api

How to retrieve Russian videos by specific category (YouTube API v3). For example, request that needed “videos category ‘Comedy’ on Russian language“:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=date&regionCode=RU&type=video&videoCategoryId=23&lr=ru_RU&key={KEY}`

I'ts not work.

I do not get a response: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4803

Comment: check this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15385454/2493918 . It's also reported as issue here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4803

Comment: Question i seen, but don't understand solution. How to retrieve Russian videos by specific category and language in YouTube API v3? Request example?

Comment: Try videoCategories instead of search. So: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&id=23&regionCode=RU&hl=ru_RU

Comment: 1. that's request return error 400 Incompatible parameters specified in the request. 2. "videoCategories method" returns a list of categories, but I need - a list of videos by category, filtered by specific language.

Answer (score 0):

I've read through this part of the YouTube API v3 Documentation:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list?hl=ru

and created this request url from the information I got there:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&id=23&regionCode=RU&hl=ru_RU&key={KEY}
```

Give it a try.

Comment: "videoCategories method" returns a list of categories, but I need - a list of videos by category

Comment: Will you be able to use API v2? Or do you really need v3?